# Input bones do not match the skeleton of the Avatar

Tags: unity-game-engine, mecanim

I'm trying to setup a model with animations from mixamo, but this error keep popping :

> The input bones do not match the skeleton of the Avatar(avatar).
>   Please check if the Avatar is generated in optimized mode, or if the
>   Avatar is valid for the attached SkinnedMeshRenderer.

I used the main fbx to generate a humanoid avatar, then imported fbx with animations and made them use that avatar.

I tried to check/uncheck "Optimize game objects", but can't see no change.
The avatar seems totally valid, as I can move every muscle as expected is the config window...

How can I find the source of this problem ?

Comment: Poking around I found [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/optmize-hierarchy-of-a-generated-skinned-mesh.340876/). See if it contains anything helpful (I can't tell for sure). If not, try reporting it as a bug to Unity.

Comment: Thanks, but I thinks it's a different error

Comment: I thought it might be, but it was as close as I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with patch 5.6.1p1  ...